# Download Entire iMessage History with One Person as Plain Text

Tags: iphone, pdf, archive

I am doing some archiving after a loss and would like to preserve a chat thread with one person in plaid text/pdf (not .HTML by date). The thread goes back 2.5years, so there is a lot. I have accessed the ~/Library/Messages folder but there is no good way to get the thread/messages into a format where i can make one large file of all of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The Messages app stores history in `~/Library/Messages/chat.db`, which is a database in SQLite format. To open it and inspect it, you'll need to install the SQLite tools, which are available from the [SQLite website](https://sqlite.org/download.html) or from Homebrew with `brew install sqlite`.

In a terminal, run `sqlite3 ~/Library/Messages/chat.db`, which will open the sqlite3 command line. Type `SELECT * FROM handle;` and search for the relevant conversation - its ID is the number in the first column.

Next, run `.output filename.txt` to set a path for the output to be saved, and
then run the following command, replacing 12345 with the ID of the conversation you're exporting.

```
SELECT handle_id, date, datetime(date / 1000000000,'unixepoch','31 years'), text 
FROM message T1 
INNER JOIN chat_message_join T2 
    ON T2.chat_id=12345
    AND T1.ROWID=T2.message_id 
ORDER BY T1.date;
```

You will now have a text file, `filename.txt`, containing this conversation in chronological order. You can run `.schema message` to see the full list of columns if you would like to save more data - simply add a comma and the name of the column onto the SELECT statement.

Comment: And the date of each message?

Comment: See my edit - I've explained how to export some other message information.

Comment: Got it! Thanks to a couple of stack overflow answers. My first line is now SELECT handle_id, date, datetime(date / 1000000000,'unixepoch','31 years'), text   
Apple date/time is unix-like dates but from 1 Jan 2001 and since Mojave(?) are in nanoseconds. I will leave you to modify your answer - I have already upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the app [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) which can extract an entire Messages conversation from first to last message, including images, into a PDF file. I believe they still have a free trial available so you can see if it works for you. It is also a very powerful tool for working on iOS devices outside of the limited Apple app access.

<sub>*Disclaimer*: I'm a satisfied user of iExplorer both personally and professionally, and have no financial or other interests in Macroplant LLC.</sub>